# How to add more than one row in Slick Carousel?

Tags: jquery

I am using this Slick Carousel for my website design..

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Every thing is fine and I wonder can more than one row can be added in this plugin??

Because i had to create a 3 Row i.e 9 elements in one Slide and other 9 in another as 3 elements in one row..

Comment: This sounds more like a feature request which should be directed to the creator of that code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you want is set one element for a slick as a 3x3 element. Slick searchs for the `divs` inside main `div` so what you need to do is inside that `div` place your 3x3 elements. Maybe a fiddle will explain more efficiently.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rzJq9/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but not manually ,is there any way using JQuery..

like binding every 9 elements as 3X3 in one `div` and like wise other 9 elements in another